# How to add new method chaining for Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I try to add new method for simplify and reusable code but I failed

User Model :

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}

public function obsolate()
{
    return $this->where('status', 'obsolate');
}
```

When I try to retrieve like `auth()->user()->products()->obsolate()` it gives some error like

> ***BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::obsolate()***

But If I do like `auth()->user()->products()->where('status', 'obsolate')->get()` It works.

Please, correct me if I wrong...

---

## UPDATE

Product Model :

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function scopeObsolate($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 'obsolate');
}
```

I do `auth()->user()->products->obsolate()->get()` and it works!

But, if I want to use [constraint group](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping) to solve this [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589260/auth-user-relations-get-not-filtered-because-orwhere) it will return error

```
public function scopeObsolate(Builder $builder)
{
    return $builder->where(function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->where('status', 'obsolate');
    });
}
```

> ***Argument 1 passed to App\Product::App{closure}() must be an instance of App\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given***

---

### SOLVED

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `products()` method return `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` object. When you applying `where` to it, laravel will set the constraints on the relation query(It means `Product` eloquent builder). So you need to defined the method in Product model.

And change the `obsolate` method to [scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes) method:

```php
// Product model:
public function scopeObsolate($query)
{
    return $query->where('status', 'obsolate');
}
```

### Update:

The second error occurs because the type-hint, laravel cannot find the `Builder` in model. You need to

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
```

Comment: It works. But, It causing error when I add `->where(function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('status', 'obsolate');
        })->get();` I should use this to constraint query like https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Comment: @ElboS.P. don't apply `get()`, check https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: Argument 1 passed to App\User::App\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given

Comment: I use https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#parameter-grouping to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61589260/auth-user-relations-get-not-filtered-because-orwhere problem.

Comment: Yea it works but it does not when i try to use ->where((function (Builder $query))

Comment: @ElboS.P. Or you want something like this: `auth()->user()->products()->where(function (Builder $query) { $query->obsolate();})->get()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213238/discussion-between-elbo-s-p-and-tsaikoga).

Comment: Yea! scope is very useful. Thanks. I will update it again later.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using Laravel, but:

Your `->where`/`->hasMany` seems to return different (internal) object that does not contain your custom method.

To chain properly, return `$this` only:

```php
class FooBar extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent
{

    public function products()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\Product');

        return $this;
    }

    public function obsolate()
    {
        $this->where('status', 'obsolate');

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: It causing error in Laravel like `App\User::products must return a relationship instance.`

Comment: @ElboS.P. just make sure you extend correct parent class

Comment: this cannot work, because `products()` need to return the relationship. however, you are returning `$this` means User object. However, OP want the datas of product.